# argparse: how to make group of options required only as group

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse, command-line-arguments

I am using `python2.7` and `argparse` for my script. I am executing script as below:

> python2.7 script.py -a valuefora -b valueforb -c valueforc -d valueford

Now what I want is that,

1. if option  `-a` is given, then only `-b`, `-c`, `-d` options should be asked.
2. In addition to above, I also want to make this group `-a -b -c -d` as a **EITHER OR** for `-e` i.e. `([-a -b -c -d] | -e )`

Please correct me anywhere I am wrong.

Comment: if the actual usage is [`(-a [-bcd] | -e)`](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=Usage%3A%0D%0A++script.py+a+%5B-bcd%5D%0D%0A++script.py+e%0D%0A%0D%0A%0D%0A&argv=a+-b) then you should convert `a`, `e` into commands e.g., using subparsers.

Answer (score 3):

Your best choice is to test for the presence of various combinations after `parse_args` and use `parser.error` to issue an `argparse` compatible error message.  And write your own `usage` line.  And make sure the defaults clearly indicate whether an option has been parsed or not.

If you can change the `-a` and `-e` options to command names like `cmda` or `build`, you could use subparsers.  In this case you might define a `command_a` subparser that accepts -b, -c, and -d, and another `command_e` subparser that has none of these.  This is closes `argparse` comes to 'required together' groups of arguments.

`mutually exclusive groups` can define something with a usage like `[-a -b -c]`, but that just means `-b` cannot occur along with `-a` and `-c`.  But there's nothing fancy about that mechanism.  It just constructs a dictionary of such exclusions, and checks it each time it parses a new option.  If there is a conflict it issues the error message and quits.  It is not set up to handle fancy combinations, such as your `(-e | agroup)`.

Custom actions can also check for the absence or presence of non-default values in the `namespace`, much as you would after parsing.  But doing so during parsing isn't any simpler.  And it raises questions about order.  Do you want to handle `-b -c -a` the same way as `-a -c -b`?  Should `-a` check for the presence of the others, or should `-b` check that `-a` has already been parsed?  Who checks for the presence, or absence of `-e`.

The are a number of other stack questions about argparse groups, exclusive and inclusive, but I think these are the essential issues.

Comment: I have used combinations after parsing args to verify. subparsers looks good option, which i will try for future.